# How do I find the Mac address of a paired device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth, headphones, mac-address

There is a Bluetooth Headphone which paired to my Android Device.

I want to know what is the Mac Address of the Headphone.

Is there any way to find the Mac Address of the paired device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `Bluetooth Headphone` *Paired* with Device, you can find Mac Address with this Apps :

[Bluetooth Finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=savvas.pamboukas.bluetoothfinder)

or

[Bluetooth Address Finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ccpcreations.android.bluetoothmacfinder)

Comment: I tried both, but doesn't recognize the Headphone for pairing process!

Comment: i used this apps and worked fine.maybe your Headphone outside Support of this apps.but,i suggest check this link : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795424/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-devices-as-a-list` this is maybe can help you with List Devices and then you can see all Devices with MAC address.hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the MAC address of a device that was already in the paired list, but was not currently connected.  The app Bluetooth Mac Finder worked for me.  It has 3 tabs at the top: Discover | Paired | My Device
The Paired tab will show the friendly name and the address of all items in your paired list.  The other two tabs do as you would expect. Discover will scan for devices and My Device shows you the MAC address of your phone.

Comment: Hello TML. Can you link this app in the answer?